# How do I make a command where you can send a file to a certain user in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.command()
async def sendfile(user: discord.User, *, file: discord.File):
    """Send a file to a user."""
    
    await user.send(content="here you go", file=discord.File(file))




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1233, in _actual_conversion
    return converter(argument)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\file.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.fp = open(fp, 'rb')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<@1065847074253443205>'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1015, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 932, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 839, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param, attachments)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 709, in transform
    return await run_converters(ctx, converter, argument, param)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1342, in run_converters
    return await _actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\berka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1242, in _actual_conversion
    raise BadArgument(f'Converting to "{name}" failed for parameter "{param.name}".') from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "File" failed for parameter "file".
@bot.command()
async def sendfile(user: discord.User, file: discord.File):
    """Send a file to a user."""
    
    await user.send(content="here you go", file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive a file on command, reference [discord.Attachment](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#attachment).
Then you will need to convert this attachment to a [discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#file) and send it to the target.
So your command should look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def sendfile(user: discord.User, attachment: discord.Attachment):
    """Send a file to a user."""
    file = await attachment.to_file()
    await user.send(content="here you go", file=file)
```